# randomly sample a list of entries with given value from a random matrix

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, data-analysis, sampling, random-matrices

There is a matrix, e.g., `M*N`, which consists of `0` and `1` values. The distribution of 0 and 1 is random. To perform an experiment, I need to randomly sample `x` entries from this matrix, these `x` entries are all of `1`. The output should be the position of these `x` entries. Are there any algorithms that can perform this functionality?

Comment: are you looking for an algorithm or something?

Answer (score 0):

Sure: randomly pick $1 \le i \le M$, $i \le j \le M$, and look at entry $(i, j)$. If it's a 1, return $(i, j)$; otherwise try again. This is known as "rejection sampling", and it's pretty slow if the probability that an entry is 1 happens to be small, and very fast if that probability is large. But it always works. :)